# xsl performance issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having trouble with the performance of an xsl mapper.
Here is some example xsl (note: the real xsl goes on like this for 10 000 lines)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var" version="1.0" xmlns:ns3="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X/2.3.1/Tables" xmlns:ns4="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X/2.3.1/DataTypes" xmlns:ns0="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X/2.3.1/Segments" xmlns:ns2="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X" xmlns:ns1="http://Cegeka.C2M.Accelerator.Schemas.segments_C2M">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/ns2:ADT_231_GLO_DEF" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/ns2:ADT_231_GLO_DEF">
<ns2:ADT_231_GLO_DEF>
  <xsl:for-each select="EVN_EventType">
    <EVN_EventType>
      <xsl:if test="normalize-space(EVN_1_EventTypeCode/text())">
        <EVN_1_EventTypeCode>
          <xsl:value-of select="EVN_1_EventTypeCode/text()" />
        </EVN_1_EventTypeCode>
      </xsl:if>
      <EVN_2_RecordedDateTime>
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(EVN_2_RecordedDateTime/TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent/text())">
          <TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent>
            <xsl:value-of select="EVN_2_RecordedDateTime/TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent/text()" />
          </TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent>
        </xsl:if>
      </EVN_2_RecordedDateTime>
      <xsl:for-each select="EVN_3_DateTimePlannedEvent">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent/text())">
          <EVN_3_DateTimePlannedEvent>
            <TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent>
              <xsl:value-of select="TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent/text()" />
            </TS_0_TimeOfAnEvent>
          </EVN_3_DateTimePlannedEvent>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:if test="normalize-space(EVN_4_EventReasonCode/text())">
        <EVN_4_EventReasonCode>
          <xsl:value-of select="EVN_4_EventReasonCode/text()" />
        </EVN_4_EventReasonCode>
      </xsl:if>
    </EVN_EventType>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </ns2:ADT_231_GLO_DEF>
   </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

So what I am doing is:

```
- I copy the nodes I want from the source xml
- I don't copy the empty nodes or the nodes that contain a break (hence why I check normalize-space(/text())
```

Now the execution time is about 1 second, is this normal? I use this mapping in biztalk which can normally process at least 10 messages per second (if not many more :p) but this map is causing a delay, so I can only process 1 message per second :(

Now I am not an xsl guru unfortunatly so if anyone can give me some advice, it is welcome :)

Thx

Comment: You don't say what size the source message is: that's going to be the main factor that determines execution time. You also don't say how you are measuring execution time - are you including XML parsing time? You can often get a useful diagnostic by establishing whether the execution time varies linearly or (say) quadratically with source document size - that is, if the size doubles does the elapsed time go up by a factor of 2, or 4, or worse? If it's quadratic, then you can often solve the problem by judicious use of xsl:key.

Comment: Although not really addressing your question w.r.t. performance, there are some 'cute' recursive XSLT template matching algorithms to generically strip out empty nodes - this might save you a lot of coding? e.g. http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200403/post50690.html

Comment: Would you mind to at least post well-formed XML? I cannot even properly format your code, not to speak about analyzing and understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

> I copy the nodes I want from the source xml
>
> I don't copy the empty nodes or the nodes that contain a break (hence why I check normalize-space)

**First**, I suggest you can use identity transform with overrides. For example the code below will copy all elements, excluding those "with empty (after whitespace normalization) string values and no child elements or attributes".

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space()) and not(*) and not(@*)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Second**, you can try to strip the unused whitespaces in compile-time, by using:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

This way your document will be kept in memory without insignificant whitespaces and thus will be more concise.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But is this method not bad for performance? Because it has to iterate over each node.. thx :)

Comment: It sure is a more natural way than tons of if statements. You can at least test it.

Comment: +1 Good advice for a starting point... If `xsl:strip-space` is suitable (not XHMTL input, i.e.) then the pattern could become `*[not(node()|@*)]`